# How to process a request that has multiple inputs and multiple files at the same time

Tags: html, forms, go, input

Building a backend go server that can take a form with multiple inputs and 3 of them have multiple file inputs. I searched and it states that if you want to make something like this work you don't want to use the typical

```
if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // get a reference to the fileHeaders
    files := r.MultipartForm.File["coverArt"]
```

and instead you should use

```
mr, err := r.MultipartReader()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
```

Standard form-data:

1. Name
2. Email
3. Cover art photos (multiple files)
4. Profile photos (multiple files)
5. 2 Audio files (2 songs)
6. 2 Videos (personal intro, recording of person in a cappella)

HTML Form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input name="coverArt" type="file"  multiple />
        <input name="profile" type="file"  multiple />
        <input type="file" name="songs"  multiple />
        <input type="file" name="videos"  multiple/>

        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
 </form>
```

Go Code:

```
func FilePOST(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    fmt.Println("File Upload Endpoint Hit")
    mr, err := r.MultipartReader()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    
    for {
        part, err := mr.NextPart()

        // This is OK, no more parts
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        // Some error
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)          
        }

        // CoverArt 'files' part
        if part.FormName() == "coverArt" {
            name := part.FileName()
            outfile, err := os.Create("uploads/" + name)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
            defer outfile.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(outfile, part)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
        }

        // Profile Pic 'files' part
        if part.FormName() == "profile" {
            name := part.FileName()
            outfile, err := os.Create("uploads/" + name)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
            defer outfile.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(outfile, part)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
        }

        // Songs 'files' part
        if part.FormName() == "songs" {
            name := part.FileName()
            outfile, err := os.Create("uploads/" + name)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
            defer outfile.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(outfile, part)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
        }

        // Video 'files' part
        if part.FormName() == "videos" {
            name := part.FileName()
            outfile, err := os.Create("uploads/" + name)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
            defer outfile.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(outfile, part)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                // return
            }
        }

    }

    fmt.Println("done")
    return nil
}
```

Go Server Error:
go run main.go                                                                                                 [15:58:21]
now serving at the following location www.localhost:3000
File Upload Endpoint Hit
INFO[0009] POST /upload                                  elapsed="680.422µs" host= method=POST path=/upload query=
2021/07/14 15:58:32 http: panic serving [::1]:62924: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: Why did you comment out all the `return` statements on errors (though there's a couple which aren't there at all)? You can't continue using possibly `nil` or invalid values if you got an error.

Comment: That was done by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to guess where your code panics. Probably the reason is that your program continue to execute when error occurs. For example if creation of file fails, `outfile.Close()` will panic as the `outfile` is nil.

Both approaches support multiple files for single field. The difference is in how they handle memory. The streaming version reads small portions of data from the network and writes it to a file when you call `io.Copy`. The other variant loads all the data into memory when you call `ParseMultiForm()`, so it requires as much memory as the size of the files you want to transfer. Below you will find working examples for both variants.

Streaming variant:

```golang
func storeFile(part *multipart.Part) error {
    name := part.FileName()
    outfile, err := os.Create("uploads/" + name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer outfile.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(outfile, part)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func filePOST(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    fmt.Println("File Upload Endpoint Hit")
    mr, err := r.MultipartReader()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for {
        part, err := mr.NextPart()

        // This is OK, no more parts
        switch {
        case errors.Is(err, io.EOF):
            fmt.Println("done")
            return nil
        case err != nil:
            // Some error
            return err
        default:
            switch part.FormName() {
            case "coverArt", "profile", "songs", "videos":
                if err := storeFile(part); err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        err := filePOST(writer, request)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(writer, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            log.Println("Error", err)
        }
    })
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And version with `ParseMultipartForm`, which reads data to memory.

```
func storeFile(part *multipart.FileHeader) error {
    name := part.Filename
    infile, err := part.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer infile.Close()
    outfile, err := os.Create("uploads/" + name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer outfile.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(outfile, infile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func FilePOST(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    fmt.Println("File Upload Endpoint Hit")
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(2 << 24); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, fileType := range []string{"coverArt", "profile", "songs", "videos"} {
        uploadedFiles, exists := r.MultipartForm.File[fileType]
        if !exists {
            continue
        }
        for _, file := range uploadedFiles {
            if err := storeFile(file); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        err := FilePOST(writer, request)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(writer, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            log.Println("Error", err)
        }
    })
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```